# Go type constraint that describes mutable struct behavior

Tags: go, pointers, generics, types, initialization

I would like to define a generic function where the type constraint describes mutable struct behavior.

What I mean by a "mutable behavior", is an interface like this:

```golang
type Unmarshaler interface {
    Unmarshal(data []byte) error
}
```

... where an implementation looks something like this:

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Content string
}

func (f *Foo) Unmarshal(data []byte) error {
    f.Content = string(data)
    return nil
}
```

Calling the interface method *mutates* the struct.

What I'd like to be able to do is define a generic function where the type constraint is the above interface. The generic function is responsible for initializing an instance of the concrete type, and then using the interface method to mutate and return it.

```golang
func Unmarshal[T Unmarshaler](data []byte) (T, error) {
    var m T
    return m, m.Unmarshal(data)
}
```

So I'd like to be able to call that generic function, using the type Foo.

```golang
func main() {
    foo, err := Unmarshal[*Foo]([]byte("hello"))
    if err == nil {
        log.Println(foo.Content) // hello
    } else {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I must pass `*Foo` as the type parameter, because only a pointer to `Foo` implements the `Unmarshaler` interface. But this panics when Foo's `Unmarshal` method receives a `nil` value for `f`. That all makes sense to me, since `var m T` is going to make a zero value of a pointer to `Foo`, and that is nil. But I'm not sure if I've just run into a dead end?

https://go.dev/play/p/H5s59NWNiDA

As best I can describe, I run into this problem any time my type constraint describes some mutable struct behavior, and my generic function wants to initialize, then mutate, an instance of the struct. Is this possible? Is there a better way to frame this?

Comment: There is no concept of “mutable” in an interface, you can even have non-pointer receivers with mutable data, like a slice for example. In practice you can’t really enforce _how_ an interface is implemented, any interface could be implemented incorrectly. Structuring these types of functions like in most other libraries by passing values avoids this type of issues.

Comment: I get that @JimB. The mutability is in the struct implementation itself, which is what forces me to deal with a _pointer_ to Foo. And that is why the generic function then can't initialize the appropriate type to make the method call actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem is creating a useful value for some type `T`.  There are several ways do this: `m := make(T)` (maps and channels), etc.  You can use `reflect` package to create the value, but it's simpler to have the caller pass the value as an argument.

```
func Unmarshal[T Unmarshaler](m T, data []byte) (T, error) {
    return m, m.Unmarshal(data)
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
foo, err := Unmarshal(&Foo{}, []byte("hello"))
```

https://go.dev/play/p/LbSuiXe9zOu

Comment: Yeah, my example code simplifies my _actual_ situation to the point where passing a value seems like a solid solution. I tried to explain that part of the context of the problem is that

"my generic function wants to initialize, then mutate, an instance of the struct". 

Ultimately, in my situation, I can't get initialized values passed into the generic method. I drew up this other simplification that comes a little closer to what I'm actually doing, might help show why I can't initialize a value and pass it to the generic method. 

https://go.dev/play/p/0Fvnz01O7uq

Comment: Ultimately, you helped me narrow my question down to "how can a generic function initialize a _useful_ variable for a pointer type?" And just putting that in words helps me find other questions asking basically the same thing, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573113/how-can-i-instantiate-a-non-nil-pointer-of-type-argument-with-generic-go